# What is Django commend equivalent to Rails' $ rails db drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

Something must be very very wrong. It can't be this hard.

I'm trying to drop tables on my Django app, which is made from default sqlite3 ORM.

Every time I want to `$ python manage.py makemigrations`, Django asks me how I want to handle new field on already existing rows and I hate it.

So what I want to do is just drop all tables from my model 'Post' and make new migrations.

This is easily done by 
`$ rails db drop; rails db migrate` on Rails but I can't find any commend equivalent to this on Django.

I've googled and I found a commend like `$ python manage.py flush` but it effectively flushes all my tables, even my Superuser.

I don't want that and I want to drop a table from a specific app.

Some posts even said I have to manually delete all migrations files and `db.sqlite3` but I bet there's another way.

One more alternative I think think of is to open `manage.py` shell and delete them like below (which I learned from the official documentation's tutorial)

`$ python manage.py shell`

`>> from posts.models import Post`

`>> Post.objects.all().delete()`

I hope it's not the way it should be.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. `rails db drop` does remove the whole database, not a specific table. It's the same as removing the sqlite file. (But note you should not delete migrations, that is almost never the right thing to do.)

Comment: It seems you should just remove the model definition in your models.py,  and makemigrations  then migrate will drop the table in db which mapping the model

Comment: @DanielRoseman So what you're saying is: `rails db drop` IS equivalent to `python manage.py flush`, right?

Comment: No, `python manage.py flush` removes just the data. `rails db drop` removes all data, tables and the database itself. `rm db.sqlite3` is equivalent to `rails db drop`.

Comment: @knbk Okay I see the difference. But which one should I use in my scenario? I just wanna delete a table from a specific app and leave all else intact - including my superuser for django admin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no django command to delete the database, or even drop a table. The only way is, like you said, to delete the `db.sqlite3` and then remove everything (except `__init__.py`) from the migrations folder before running `makemigrations` and `migrate`. If you find this cumbersome just put it in a shell script that's what I do.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to recommend removing the migrations. The whole point of migrations is that they will recreate everything from scratch.

Comment: Wow that's a big bummer. I thought it was my fault for not being able to find these on the official documentation. So if I want to delete a table, I actually have to remove db.sqlite3 and everything except `__init__` in the migration folder? 

Why did they do that? Django is already at 2.1 so is there any good reason for not making such commend? Or is it just Django folks being lazy?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It depends on the reason you're starting clean slate. Say you wanted to change a field name on a model. Deleting the db, changing the model, then running `makemigrations` will give you an error.

Comment: @zebralamy Yeah personally i think its unfortunate. I can't speak for the creators of Django as to why they don't have this option, but it's something that comes up fairly commonly so i trust it's for good cause. If you're invested enough though you could write a custom django command which does what you like. Check out https://medium.com/@frfahim/custom-management-command-in-django-b5ba1e6ea4a2 as an example

Comment: @stackPusher Thanks for sharing your knowledge!